# Android Licensing on Custom Roms

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Does the android licensing work on custom Roms, too?

If yes, then what could it be that some people can't install (=> "device incompatible") my app from market?

Comment: What custom ROMs do you refer to?

Comment: For example someone with cyanogenmod 7(Android 2.3.7) on a LG 970 claimed that he can't install/update my app anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the custom rom come with the default Android market app, I don't think this has anything to do with neither Android licensing nor your app. It looks more like a fault from cyanogenmod ROM Customization, check out [here](http://androidforums.com/motorola-triumph/459784-apps-incompatible-after-installing-cm7.html) for the reported problem and workaround.

My app has also got some negative feedback from cyanogenmod user complain HTTP Live Streaming doesn't work, as it turned out, a bug from cyanogenmod ROM Customization. LOL